# 【googleフォームとスプシの連携】設定した質問のプルダウンを、シートから引っ張りたい。

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

”従業員”というフォーム内の質問の回答にプルダウンで回答してもらいます。
スプシの「プルダウン」タブ，K2:Kがプルダウンに入る内容です。（K1はタイトルです）

というわけで、以下のコードを作成しましたが、エラーが出てしまい上手くいきません。
2つのサイトを参考にやったのですが、、、ご教授ください。

```
function empList() {

  /**
  // スプレッドシートの情報を取得する
  // 
  **/

  //スプレッドシートのID　→「https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/△△△/edit#gid=0」の△△△を↓に記述
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('△△△').getSheets();

// タブ「プルダウン」の情報を取得
var sheetName = "プルダウン"; 

// スプレッドシート上のシートオブジェクトを取得
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);


  // スプレッドシートのK1のセルが従業員名（フォームのプルダウン）の場合
  if("従業員名（フォームのプルダウン）" == sheet.getRange("K1").getValue()){

    // K行の2行目からコンテンツをもつ最後の行までの値を配列で取得する
    var colA = sheet.getRange(2, 11, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  }

  /**
  // Googleフォームのプルダウン内の値を上書きする
  // 
  **/

  // GoogleフォームのIDを設定　→「https://docs.google.com/forms/d/〇〇〇/edit」の〇〇〇を↓に記述
  var form = FormApp.openById('〇〇〇');

  // 質問項目がプルダウンのもののみ取得
  var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);

  items.forEach(function(item){
    // 質問項目が「従業員」を含むものに対して、スプレッドシートの内容を反映する
    if(item.getTitle().match(/従業員.*$/)){
      var listItemQuestion = item.asListItem();
      var choices = [];

      colA.forEach(function(name){
        if(name != ""){
          choices.push(listItemQuestion.createChoice(name));
        }
      });

      // プルダウンの選択肢を上書きする
      listItemQuestion.setChoices(choices);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: 参考にしたという2つのサイト/記事へのリンクと、発生・通知されたエラーメッセージの詳細をテキストで追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)